# How to exclude user/audience from displaying ads in Google Ads API, in real-time?

Tags: google, google-ads, marketing

I want to exclude the user from displaying my ads once he/she clicks my ad; in real-time. So next time he/she should not be displayed same ad again and again.

Is there any such api provided by google ads ?

The concern is, Google, for example targets 1000 users for Rs100 daily but as we see only 400 leads are genuine and rest 600 are just the duplication of 400 genuine leads.

So we theoretically made a plan that, if google provides any such api when user clicks the ad, then that api should be called automatically and add that user to exclusion list. So next time the same ad must not be displayed to him/her.

I also asked the same question on [Google Ads Help Community.](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/153815539?hl=en)

PS. I am a Laravel Developer, working on this issue to find any real time solution, have moderate knowledge of google ads, *not its API.*